# Memoization for subsequent fold calls

Tags: haskell, memoization, fold

I'm looking for a technique that allows for memoization between subsequent fold calls against the lists that is being prepended.

I looked at [memoize library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/memoize) but this doesn't seem to support memoization of higher-order functions, which is the case for folds.

I also tried the technique with lazy evaluated map of results but to no avail.

Here's simple example code:

```
module Main where

import Data.Time

printAndMeasureTime :: Show a => a -> IO ()
printAndMeasureTime a = do
  startTime <- getCurrentTime
  print a
  stopTime <- getCurrentTime
  putStrLn $ " in " ++ show (diffUTCTime stopTime startTime)

main = do
  let as = replicate 10000000 1
  printAndMeasureTime $ foldr (-) 0 as -- just to resolve thunks
  printAndMeasureTime $ sum as
  printAndMeasureTime $ sum (1:as) -- recomputed from scratch, could it reuse previous computation result?
  printAndMeasureTime $ length (as)
  printAndMeasureTime $ length (1:as) -- recomputed from scratch, could it reuse previous computation result?
```

and the output:

```
0
 in 1.125098223s
10000000
 in 0.096558168s
10000001
 in 0.104047058s
10000000
 in 0.037727126s
10000001
 in 0.041266456s
```

Times suggest that folds are computed from scratch. Is there a way to make the subsequent folds reuse previous fold results?

Comment: You should be careful with measurements like this. The fact that you added IO between the things you want to measure may well have caused the compiler to emit different code for them. Also note that memoisation is always a bit of a clutch; If you have a need for things like this see if you can't cache the results "normally" first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a data type!

```
module List (List, _elements, _sum, _length, toList, cons) where

data List = List
  { _elements :: [Int]
  , _sum :: !Int
  , _length :: !Int
  }

toList :: [Int] -> List
toList xs = List xs (sum xs) (length xs)

cons :: Int -> List -> List
cons x (List xs t n) = List (x:xs) (x+t) (1+n)
```

Note that the `List` type is exported, but the `List` constructor is not, so that the only way to construct a `List` is using the `toList` function (commonly called a "smart constructor").